# NameError: global name 'flask' is not defined

Tags: python, twitter, routes

I am fairly new to Python web programming. Request your assistance in handling the error I am getting while running a test application please. Trying to run the command - python run.py - from Powershell. It gives the error given in the title. [Trying the instructions provided in this link](https://thelaziestprogrammer.com/sharrington/web-development/tweet-archiver-with-flask-and-tweepy-part-1)

### run.py

```
from tweet_harvester import app
app.run(port=8080)
```

### Config.py

```
import os
DEBUG = True 
TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = os.environ['TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY']
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = os.environ['TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET']
TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN = os.environ['TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN']
TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = os.environ['TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET']
```

### **init**.py

```
from flask import Flask, json, request, render_template
import tweepy
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(app.config['TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY'],app.config['TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET'])
auth.set_access_token(app.config['TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN'],app.config['TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET'])
tweepy_api = tweepy.API(auth)

def get_tweets(username):
tweets = tweepy_api.user_timeline(screen_name=username) 
return [{'tweet': t.text,'created_at': t.created_at,'username': username, 'headshot_url': t.user.profile_image_url} 
for t in tweets]

@app.route('/tweet-harvester/<string:username>')
def tweets(username):
return flask.render_template('tweets.html', tweets=get_tweets(username))
```

### tweets.html - pasting only the relevant portion of header and body section

```
<title>Tweet Harvester</title>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="p-3">Tweet Harvester</h1>
    {% for tweet in tweets %}
    <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
          <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <img src="{{tweet.headshot_url}}" class="w-12 p-1 float-left image-thumbnail">
            <h5 class="ml-10 w-75 mb-1">{{ tweet.tweet }}</h5>
            <small>{{ tweet.created_at }}</small>
          </div>
        </a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not imported render_template from flask. You need to import it before using.

```
from flask import render_template
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you are using the render_template incorrectly I guess.
It should be `flask.render_template()`

OR (better) for using it in your way you just need to import it from flask as

```
from flask import render_template
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Have modified the code to include importing of render_template. __init__.py file now looks like - from flask import Flask, json, request, render_template
import tweepy But the issue still persists.

Comment: @AshwinKumar Seems like you still haven't modified the *init.py* . If Yes, update your post too.

Comment: And for just trying out things  Please try
`return flask.render_template('tweets.html', tweets=get_tweets(username))`

Comment: Have updated __init__. Please have a look at the post to see how it appears now. With these updates I now get the error " NameError: global name 'flask' is not defined ".

Comment: @AshwinKumar This is weird ! try a basic simple flask app (very minimal ) and see if its still there.

Comment: Sorry man for delayed response. Was held up with lot of things. Will try your suggestion in few days and see if that makes any difference. Good Weekend

Comment: Yeah, please try and revert, if you still need any help :)